# AIDL method is not generated

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-service-binding

I need to pass an `Intent` object to remote service through AIDL, I tried:

In aidl file:

```
import android.content.Intent;
parcelable Intent

void passIntent(Intent intent);
```

In my remote serivce class:

```
private final IMyService.Stub mBinder = new IMyService.Stub() {
  //ERROR: The method must override or implement a supertype method
  @Override
  public void passIntent(Intent intent) {

  }
}
```

I got compilation error `The method must override or implement a supertype method`.

Then I checked gen/ folder, IMyService.java, the method is not generated. Project clean & re-build doesn't help.

Why? Does Android not allow to pass `Intent` object in this way?  If so, how can I pass `Intent` object from Activity to service in another process?

Comment: Try removing the `parcelable Intent` line from your AIDL.

Comment: @CommonsWare, It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I created a new Android Studio project and defined this AIDL based on your question:

```
package com.commonsware.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;

interface IMyService {
    void passIntent(Intent intent);
}
```

I received a build error:

```
.../IMyService.aidl:6 parameter 1: 'Intent intent' can be an out parameter, so you must declare it as in, out or inout.
```

Changing the AIDL to:

```
package com.commonsware.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;

interface IMyService {
    void passIntent(in Intent intent);
}
```

resulted in `IMyService.java` being generated with the proper method.

So, add the `in` keyword to your `passIntent()` declaration, and try that.